Summation of Binomial Coefficient containing negative r
In my book it is given:
$$\sum_{r=0}^nr(^nC_r)=n\cdot2^{n-1}$$
But if I prove it this way
$$\implies\sum_{r=0}^nr(^nC_r)$$
$$\implies \sum_{r=0}^nr\cdot\left(\frac{n}{r}\right)\space ^{n-1}C_{r-1}$$
$$\implies n\sum_{r=0}^n{^{n-1}C_{r-1}}$$
Opening the summation would give
$$n[^{n-1}C_{-1}+^{n-1}C_{0}+^{n-1}C_{1}+^{n-1}C_{2}+.....+^{n-1}C_{n-1}]$$
How is negative number possible in the lower index

Your second step where you introduce $n/r$ is not valid for the $r=0$ term of the sum. That term is zero anyway, since it has a factor of $r$. So just drop it from the sum and your negative index goes away.

Well, $n/r$ can't be written when $r=0.$ So the statement $\binom nr=\frac nr\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ is wrong when $r=0.$

Luckiily, $r\binom nr$ is always zero when $r=0.$

Using the continuous definition of the factorial, $x!=\int_0^\infty t^x\mathrm{e}^{-t},\mathrm{d}t$, it turns out that $(-1)!$ is undefined, so $\binom{n-1}{-1}=\frac{(n-1)!}{n!(-1)!}=\frac{1}{n(-1)!}=0$

@user469053 Thanks, that makes complete sense

You just need to do this:-
$$\sum_{r=0}^n r (^{n}C_r) = 0 + \sum_{r=1}^n r (^{n} C_r)$$
This removes the ambiguity when $r=0$.
After this, following your steps gives the answer as
$$n[^{n-1}C_0+^{n-1}C_1+....^{n-1}C_{n-1}]$$
By binomial theorem we know that $(1+x)^{(n-1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\ $$^{n-1}$ $C_kx^{k}$. Putting $1=x$ gives sum of coefficients as $2^{n-1}$.
Hence value of the summation$=n×2^{n-1}$.
